# Not able to get object values

Tags: javascript

My array:

```
[
 {
    "date":"2018-04-01",
    "time":[{"10:00":"12"},{"12:00":"25"}]
 },
 {
    "date":"2018-04-02",
    "time":[{"10:00":"12"},{"12:00":"25"}]
 },
 {
    "date":"2018-04-03",
    "time":[{"10:00":"12"},{"12:00":"25"}]
 }
]
```

I need to get every date and time. To get this I am using a for loop. But not able to get date and time.

My script:

```
var slots = req.body.availableSlots;
var count = slots.length;
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    console.log(slots[i]);
    console.log(slots[i].date);
}
```

When getting `date` always says `undefined`.

Comment: what r u getting in count

Comment: Can you please confirm that `req.body.availableSlots` is an object and not a string? If it is a string you need to parse it first.

Comment: If the data is really as shown, that code works: https://jsfiddle.net/a8prjyfk/

Comment: Working fine for me:-https://jsfiddle.net/hfhq0zm4/

Comment: @dev9 count of objects in array to use for loop.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it is an array given in question.

Comment: The best way to solve this sort of problem is to use a **debugger** so you can see what `slots` really is (as it clearly isn't what you've shown in the question). You can use Chrome as a debugger for Node.js code, see the `--inspect` and `--inspect-brk` flags and [this Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/). You can also use vscode to [debug Node.js code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `req.body.availableSlots` is coming as a multidimensional object array.

***So full code need to be:-***

```
var slots = req.body.availableSlots;
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    var sub_array = slots[i];
    for(j = 0; j<sub_array.length;j++){
      console.log(sub_array[j].date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jquery library (**jQuery.parseJSON()**) use javascript inbuilt **JSON.parse**

```
var slots =  '[{"date":"2018-04-01","time":[{"10:00":"12"},{"12:00":"25"}]},{"date":"2018-04-02","time":[{"10:00":"12"},{"12:00":"25"}]},{"date":"2018-04-03","time":[{"10:00":"12"},{"12:00":"25"}]}]';

slots = JSON.parse(slots);

var count = slots.length;
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    console.log(slots[i].date);
```

Comment: when i console.log(slots[i]); my console data is in array why? it should be in object!! my slots is not a string it is an array

Comment: if its array then the code you posted should be working